# Sql Server xp_cmdshell Access is denied

Tags: sql, xp-cmdshell

i'm trying to run some cmd commands via sql query xp_cmdshell 
all was working fine but when i have tried to run this code :

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net user Test Test2 /ADD'
```

i found this bad result:

```
System error 5 has occurred.
NULL
Access is denied.
NULL
NULL
```

---

can any one help me ?
sry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permission to run this, instead, speak to your Database administrator.

Comment: so how can i give my the permission

Comment: Speak to your database administrator. If you're the database administrator, find out what you need to do on [the site for DBAs](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score -1):

Run your Command Prompt with Administrative Rights by right click on the shortcut, and Run as Administrator.